# Is there a Mac OSX version of windows GetFontData function?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts

We have an application that allows our users to generate print-ready PDF documents using variable data (names, titles, phone numbers, etc) that their customer's enter via an online e-commerce website.  To facilitate the variable data we have to embed a font's entire character map.  On windows we have been using the windows API function GetFontData(...) like so:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    //this is windows specific code
    HDC DC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HFONT hFont = font.handle();
    HFONT oFont=(HFONT)SelectObject(DC,hFont);

    DWORD fontLength = ::GetFontData(DC, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if(fontLength != GDI_ERROR)
    {
        fontData.GrowAllocation(fontLength);

        if(::GetFontData(DC, 0, 0, fontData.GetBuffer(), fontLength) == GDI_ERROR)
        {
            fontData.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            fontData.SetLength(fontLength);
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }

    SelectObject(DC,oFont);
    DeleteDC(DC);
    //End of windows specific code
#elif defined(Q_WS_MAC)



#endif
```

This technique works very successfully on our windows specific version; however, we are porting the application to Qt to target the Mac OSX platform.

My first question:  Is there a Qt way of accessing the raw font data from a QFont, QFontDatabase, etc. that we could use to embed in the pdf?  We have been unable to find a way.  Notice the #ifdef wrapper in the above code.  Note that the variable fontData is a self contained memory buffer that manages its own memory, please disregard.

My second question:  If there is no Qt way of accessing the font data in an OS agnostic way, what is the OSX equivalent to the windows GetFontData?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've only skimmed documentation for `GetFontData`, and I don't know much about Qt (though it does sound like a Qt solution would be preferable), but you might want to look at the ObjC class for fonts, [NSFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks.  We've looked at NSFont and NSGraphicsContext as well as functions from ATSUI such as ATSFontActivateFromFileReference to no avail.  We are not experienced mac developers though, and may be missing some basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

The latest (until Apple hires new font people and gets infected with not-invented-here disease again) text and font API is [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_Framework_Ref/_index.html). I never used it since chasing Apple's mood is harmful to my personal and organization's financial health, I stopped using any Apple-only API. :)

Kidding aside, it looks like `CTFont` does provide access to all tables in a font. I don't see anything that prepares a font for embedding but this probably gives you the best chance.